# Add Record/Class Data to Extjs Grid Column and Not in Rows

Tags: grid, extjs4

I have a requirement to add the data in a grid panel on a event.
Note that i dont want to insert the complete rows here but want to dynamically add the data in columns.

for example when the user clicks on the checkbox whose data will go into "want" column(refer the image below) i want to populate it in the below format.
if the user clicks on the data which has to go in "dontwant" column it has to populate in below format

[image]

how can i achieve this... pls help

Comment: Please re-form your question. It's not clear what exactly are you trying to ask.

Comment: Sorry. Renaming didn't help. Still absolutely no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Raj: The item will be added to `want`/`dont want` column when you choose by ticking on the checkbox item on another list? If it is your idea, you can have a grid with 3 columns and call hide()/show() the corresponding column after adding the chosen item to gridrow.

Comment: Here is the whole question... If I add any record into a grid It will occupy the whole row. So if u try to analyse the above image where primary has a total of 5 rows. But want column has 5 data and don't want column has only 2 data in it. It is whole dynamic to m

Comment: I found the Grouping functionality on the grid panel may help. Surely it cannot be as much flexible as your needs.

Comment: No grouping don't work... But still my basic question here is. Can I put a data in the column format. Ie,, keep pushing data in column irrespective of the row index??. Can I have 10 records in column 1 and 5 data in column 2. And again with this I need a look and feel of a grid model. Thnaks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The grid is constituted from `columns` config of grid panel together with grid store structure. That means ExtJS defines the grid panel exactly a Grid with each row is a record of grid store (columns are just what field names showed on the grid). So "keep pushing data in column irrespective of the row index?" is unable to. Let's imagine this:

- How can the grid store define the "record" in your case?
- How can the grid provide methods to delete/change the "composite records"?

Don't forget that ExtJS grid is not just to display data but also to communicate with server to perform CRUD via its proxy.

You still can achieve your aim if the grid is **just for displaying data**. In this case, you create a dummy store with `fields: ['Family', 'Want', 'DontWant']` and use `columns` config to show the data. Then directly interact with records in grid store to modify 'Want'/'DontWant' value when you check/uncheck data (add new if the record not exists)

Comment: Thanks.. Did the same way, helped a lot. But my client anyway wanted to scrap this functionality after realising that it would be only to display the data and the  the page will consume the space. But thanks a lot for ur reply